# QCustomPlot: How to set percent on the y-axis? How to change tick label alignment?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, charts, qcustomplot

I am playing around with the QCustomPlot libary for Qt. I created some plots succesfully. But I got still questions:

1: How can I set my y-axis range from 0% to 100%?

2: My tick labels are centered below the ticks. How can I change that to a left alignment?

Thanks for your help.

Peter

```
// generate some data:
    QVector<double> x(101), y(101); // initialize with entries 0..100
    for (int i=0; i<101; ++i)
    {
      x[i] = (i*960); // x goes from -1 to 1
      y[i] = x[i]/96000.0; // let's plot a quadratic function
    }
    // create graph and assign data to it:
    ui->customPlot->addGraph();
    ui->customPlot->graph(0)->setData(x, y);

    // set axes ranges, so we see all data:
    ui->customPlot->xAxis->setTickLabelType(QCPAxis::ltDateTime);
    ui->customPlot->xAxis->setDateTimeSpec(Qt::UTC);
    ui->customPlot->xAxis->setDateTimeFormat("hh:mm");
    ui->customPlot->xAxis->setAutoTickStep(false);
    ui->customPlot->xAxis->setTickStep(3600);
    ui->customPlot->xAxis->setRange(0, 86399);
    ui->customPlot->yAxis->setRange(0, 1);
    ui->customPlot->replot();

ui->customPlot->xAxis->setBasePen(QPen(Qt::white, 1));
ui->customPlot->yAxis->setBasePen(QPen(Qt::white, 1));
ui->customPlot->xAxis->setTickPen(QPen(Qt::white, 1));
ui->customPlot->yAxis->setTickPen(QPen(Qt::white, 1));
ui->customPlot->xAxis->setSubTickPen(QPen(Qt::white, 1));
ui->customPlot->yAxis->setSubTickPen(QPen(Qt::white, 1));
ui->customPlot->xAxis->setTickLabelColor(Qt::white);
ui->customPlot->yAxis->setTickLabelColor(Qt::white);
ui->customPlot->xAxis->grid()->setPen(QPen(QColor(140, 140, 140), 1, Qt::DotLine));
ui->customPlot->yAxis->grid()->setPen(QPen(QColor(140, 140, 140), 1, Qt::DotLine));
ui->customPlot->xAxis->grid()->setSubGridPen(QPen(QColor(80, 80, 80), 1, Qt::DotLine));
ui->customPlot->yAxis->grid()->setSubGridPen(QPen(QColor(80, 80, 80), 1, Qt::DotLine));
ui->customPlot->xAxis->grid()->setSubGridVisible(true);
ui->customPlot->yAxis->grid()->setSubGridVisible(true);
ui->customPlot->xAxis->grid()->setZeroLinePen(Qt::NoPen);
ui->customPlot->yAxis->grid()->setZeroLinePen(Qt::NoPen);
ui->customPlot->xAxis->setUpperEnding(QCPLineEnding::esSpikeArrow);
ui->customPlot->yAxis->setUpperEnding(QCPLineEnding::esSpikeArrow);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should solve both questions with

```
ui->customPlot->yAxis->setRange(0, 100, Qt::AlignLeft);
```

EDIT: to show custom text for ticks, you should add this code:

```
QVector<double> TickValues;
QVector<QString> TickLabels;
// you can safely change the values according to the output
TickValues << 0  << 20 << 40 << 60 << 80 << 100;
TickLabels << "0" << "20%" << "40%" << "60%" << "80%" << "100%";
// disable default ticks and their labels
ui->customPlot->yAxis->setAutoTicks(false);
ui->customPlot->yAxis->setAutoTickLabels(false);
// add your custom values and labels
ui->customPlot->yAxis->setTickVector(TicksValues);
ui->customPlot->yAxis->setTickVectorLabels(TickLabels);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like to have the percent sign adjacent to my tick labels, such like "10%", "20%" and so on. How can I do that?

Unfortunately the "Qt::AlignLeft" doesn't do anything. It's still centered.

Comment: added a possible solution

Comment: The percent sign issue is solved. But the alignment still doesn't work.

Comment: I haven't found nothing on the apidoc http://www.qcustomplot.com/documentation/classQCPAxis.html

Comment: @PeterPanne That may also be solved, if you will overload or change `getTickLabel(..)` as in `QString QCPAxisTicker::getTickLabel(double tick, const QLocale &locale, QChar formatChar, int precision) { return locale.toString(tick, formatChar.toLatin1(), precision) + " %"; }`